# Java memory allocation x syscall

Tags: java, memory-management, linux-kernel

I have been reading how a program interacts with OS.

I learned that whenever a program wants to create an object/variable in memory, should pass the control to kernel do that, using a syscall, OS memory management, like jemalloc for example.

I also read that Java does not use mallac or even make a syscall when crate a variable or object on heap using *new*. As objects are create all the time, should be a high cost, so JVM is responsible for handle it.

My question is:

Can a program create data on heap without make a syscall? Creating an object directly to its memory space?

Note: I know that OS maps a virtual memory to real memory in order to protect data and so on.

Comment: What's this "SO" that you are talking about?

Comment: The Java 'heap' is a user space entity. So, creating something in the heap is a user space operation, because the kernel does not administer the heap. The kernel allocates address space for user mode code, and user mode code uses that allocated space to form a heap, in which objects can be allocated.

Comment: Sorry @Sweeper, I'm talking about OS not SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications request memory in larger chunks than individual objects to have extra to satisfy future requests. Then, once an application obtains memory from the OS, it keeps it around in a free memory pool even after it's no longer in use. If a new memory allocation request comes along, that request is satisfied from that pool of extra/freed memory if possible.

This is because it would be very inefficient to go to the OS/kernel every time an apllication wanted to allocate or free memory.

That is how the JVM can allocate new objects without going to the OS: It uses free memory that it has already gotten from the OS.

Speaking very generally, (memory used by objects < memory allocated to program).

Unused free memory can be returned to the OS if the application doesn't need it anymore, but if that's done at all, it's done after the memory is unused for a period of time.